# Why does my json file keep turning into a string of random words? (Python)

Tags: python, json, discord.py

So i'm making some scoring system type thing in python with json and discord.py, this is its code:

```
import json

def getPoints(bot, user):
    f = open('points.json', 'r')
    points = json.load(f)

    name = str(user)
    f.close()
    return points.get(name)

#later on down the line

@bot.group()
async def pointSystem(ctx):
    pass

@pointSystem.command()
async def enable(ctx):
    f = open('points.json', 'r')
    points = json.load(f)
    if points.get(str(ctx.author)) != None:
        await ctx.send('Already enabled for this user!')
        return
    io = await ui.prompt(ctx, 'This command enables the point system\nAre you sure you want to enable this?')
    if io == 'yes':
        await ctx.send('Ok, enabling...')
        points[str(ctx.author)] = 0
        f.close()
        f = open('points.json', 'w')
        json.dump(points, f, indent=4)
        f.close()
        await ctx.send('Enabled for this user!')
    else:
        await ctx.send('Alright, stopping command execution...')
        f.close()
```

in points.json i should have:

```
{}
```

And that's what i put in there originally, but sometimes, i look into points.json and i see a string with some random word in it. It doesn't give an error of any kind, it just does what i described, which doesn't make much sense, because i don't think i have any code that would set it to a string of any kind. I have no reproduction code, as i don't know the real culprit of this problem, i would point you towards doing something like what i did, which is creating a discord bot with this scoring system thing, but i don't really think even that would reproduce it.

Edit: Okay, this is getting really weird. 3 months later, with completely new code, I still have a file named "points.json" in my root directory, and it contains the random string I mentioned above, that literally makes no sense. Even when I remove it, a couple weeks later it will come back.

Comment: You have async code, but you're not e.g. locking the file you're writing to when you write it, so two or more tasks could be dumping JSON into it simultaneously...

Comment: All in all it would be better to refactor your code so all file operations are handled by separate functions, not by stuff mixed into your other bot functions.

Comment: Locking the file didn't fix it, I'm using portalocker to lock it, as fcntl isn't on windows. The JSON file is still turning into a string of random words.

Comment: Please give us an example of "a string of random words".

Comment: This is the current one: "MrNateBro"